# How to schedule or automate dataset refresh in aws quicksight

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-quicksight

What are the options available to schedule or automate refresh of a quicksight SPICE dataset?

Are there any APIs available to automate spice datatset refresh? preferably using python.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two options,

### - **Using API services available in the latest version of boto3**

Use '[create_ingestion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_ingestion)' method to initiate dataset refresh, and use '[describe_ingestion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.describe_ingestion)' to check the status of refresh

```
import boto3
import time
import sys
client = boto3.client('quicksight')
response = client.create_ingestion(DataSetId='<dataset-id>',IngestionId='<ingetion-id>',AwsAccountId='<aws-account-id>')
while True:
    response = client.describe_ingestion(DataSetId='<dataset-id>',IngestionId='<ingetion-id>',AwsAccountId='<aws-account-id>')
        if response['Ingestion']['IngestionStatus'] in ('INITIALIZED', 'QUEUED', 'RUNNING'):
            time.sleep(10) #change sleep time according to your dataset size
        elif response['Ingestion']['IngestionStatus'] == 'COMPLETED':
            print("refresh completed. RowsIngested {0}, RowsDropped {1}, IngestionTimeInSeconds {2}, IngestionSizeInBytes {3}".format(
                response['Ingestion']['RowInfo']['RowsIngested'],
                response['Ingestion']['RowInfo']['RowsDropped'],
                response['Ingestion']['IngestionTimeInSeconds'],
                response['Ingestion']['IngestionSizeInBytes']))
            break
        else:
            print("refresh failed! - status {0}".format(response['Ingestion']['IngestionStatus']))
            sys.exit(1)
```

DataSetId of dataset can be found from aws URI or use '[list_data_sets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.list_data_sets)' method to list all datasets and get DataSetId from the field ['DataSetSummaries']['DataSetId'] method call response

IngestionId - set unique id, I used current time in epoch [*str(int(time.time()))*]

### - Schedule refresh using schedule option in quicksight dataset

You can schedule refreshes for 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly' or 'monthly' cadence using schedule option in quicksight-dataset

[image]

Comment: But I guess there's no option to programmatically configure the "Schedule refresh" operation.

Neither in the API to create a DataSet nor in the Create Ingestion.

Comment: The above code worked  100%  for me just add commend : 
DataSetId of the dataset can be found from AWS URI or use the following AWS cli command to get all the list of datasets (data source ) : 

 - >  aws quicksight list-data-sources --aws-account-id xxxx5699xx

Account Id: xxxx5699xx we need to pass this parameter