# How to push the data directly to SPICE from external source like Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

- Is there a way to push the processed data directly to SPICE.
- I want to push the data (CSV File) from external resources (Jenkins) to SPICE directly.

Comment: Ok, but what is your question or issue?

Comment: Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037769/19407556